# Blocked .mil access: https://www.hrc.army.mil

Tags: security, google-chrome

https://www.hrc.army.mil/  is one of many hrc.army.mil sites that is being blocked by Google this morning. I am trying to access my family member's military records from the Department of the Army, as I was instructed.

I get a halt! page of sorts stating:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.hrc.army.mil (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
>
> Automatically report details of possible security incidents to Google. Privacy policy

This seems *wrong*. Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, someone has just forgotten to renew a SSL certificate or are using one incorrectly. (I've seen this happen a lot with government sites.)

I suggest just trying again in a few days.